# order of array changes becuase of closure (Execution order of closures in for loop)

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, closures

I have a for loop that loops through user IDs and then fetches the user with the given ID from firebase. In this case, the order of the withIds array matters. So I want my array of user objects from firebase (**usersArray**) to match the order of the (**withIds**) array. I thought that doing it in a for loop would preserve the order as I thought it would call FirebaseReference in that order, but that does not seem to be the case and user objects are appended at a different index than expected. Please help!

I also added print statements to check how the code is progressing, and the order is not **what I expected:**

step 1
v5AfWqDvg9TLxh0GyhmlRIaukow2

step 1
nM6wLjQNq0VfvsKoGDuW6gTjsbe2

step 1
n568Av3bgHcEYMmtQCAfzgZsn5C3

step 2
v5AfWqDvg9TLxh0GyhmlRIaukow2

step 2
nM6wLjQNq0VfvsKoGDuW6gTjsbe2

step 2
n568Av3bgHcEYMmtQCAfzgZsn5C3

**the actual output:**

step 1
v5AfWqDvg9TLxh0GyhmlRIaukow2

step 1
nM6wLjQNq0VfvsKoGDuW6gTjsbe2

step 1
n568Av3bgHcEYMmtQCAfzgZsn5C3

step 2
n568Av3bgHcEYMmtQCAfzgZsn5C3

step 2
nM6wLjQNq0VfvsKoGDuW6gTjsbe2

step 2
v5AfWqDvg9TLxh0GyhmlRIaukow2

```
   for userId in withIds {
            print("step 1")
            print(userId)
            FirebaseReference(.User).document(userId).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
                print("step 2")
                print(userId)
                guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
                
                if snapshot.exists {
                    
                    usersArray.append(FUser(_dictionary: snapshot.data()! as NSDictionary))

                    counter += 1
                    
                    if counter == withIds.count {
                        completion(usersArray)
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    completion(usersArray)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: To clarify: For loops **will** execute in order. You can depend on that. However, your for loop calls an async function for each entry in the array that takes a completion handler. Because it's asynchronous, it can take a variable amount of time to call it's completion handler. So while each call will be STARTED in the order of your array, it's completion handler will be called in an unpredictable order.

Comment: This is another timing issue, switching to `async await` would simplify your code

Answer (score 3):

The calls to Firebase are asynchronous so there is no guarantee on the order that the completion blocks will be called.

Here is a solution to get the desired result. The idea is to collect all of the results into a dictionary keyed off of the userId. Then once all of the results have been obtained, build the final array in the correct order.

This code makes use of a dispatch group to know when all of the results have been obtained. Also note that you only want one call to the completion handler at the end. Do not call the completion handler over and over in the loop.

```
var foundUsers = [String: FUser]() // temp dictionary to store all of the results
let group = DispatchGroup()

for userId in withIds {
    group.enter()
    FirebaseReference(.User).document(userId).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
        defer {
            group.leave()
        }

        guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }

        if snapshot.exists {
            // Save the result for later sorting
            foundUsers[userId] = FUser(_dictionary: snapshot.data()! as NSDictionary)
        }
    }
}

// This block gets called once all results have been received
group.notify(queue: .main) {
    // Put the results into the desired order
    var usersArray = [FUser]()
    for userId in withIds {
        if let user = foundUsers[userId] {
            usersArray.append(user)
        }
    }

    // Make one call to the completion handler
    completion(usersArray)
}
```

Comment: Nice use of dispatch groups (voted.)